# How to load data from excel in xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, excel, csv

I need to load data from an excel sheet into xcode. 
I've seen that if the spreadsheet is converted to a .csv format the data can be loaded in xcode.
But my spreadsheet contains too many rows so that all the rows in it cannot be saved as a .csv format..
I converted it to .csv format. But when i opened it, a dialog box appears..

```
"The maximum number of rows has been exceeded. Excess rows where not imported."
```

So how can i include my spreadsheet data in xcode?? Is there any other way to load data from spreadsheet??

Comment: do you mean the save operation result in success but when you open it for viewing it shows above error? Please clarify

Comment: @JigarPandya : Yeah... exactly.. save operation was success.. when i opened, the above error was shown..

Comment: don't open it within xcode IDE if not require. Try opening the same from other tool like www.microsoft.com/mac/excel

Comment: no.. i didn't open it in xcode.. i just opened in libre office.. then only the error was shown

Comment: i asked whether there is any other way to load data in spreadsheet to xcode..

Answer (score 0):

try opening it in some text editor or vi editor or other tool.. it should show you the data properly.

There are number of post on internet that states that you may be using older version of libre office or open office. Consider upgrade in that case.

If you have microsoft office for mac you can open it over there.

Alternatively, you can try the following:

```
$ wc -l file.csv
```

The result should be 2560 (indicating that there are 2560 lines in the file).

Hope this helps.